# C# .NET Core: Automatically save UserId in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

We have a column `UserId` which stores person who last modified the table.

Sometimes, people modify customer, address tables, through C# .NET Core application.

There are `UserId`s in web application, obviously not stored as SQL Server logins.

Ex:  `JoeSmith` (`UserId` = 8) is a login in the C# application, but not in SQL Server.

If person runs a transaction which modifies 5 tables concurrently, is there an easy way to conduct change all `UserId`s in all 5 tables, automatically? Without laboriously adding `UserId` in all the Linq-EF queries, and modifying all auto mappers?

Looking for a simple way to conduct this,

Is it possible to set a fake `UserId` through Entity Framework, and have the `userId` values default to whoever is running the application?

Trying to research:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/system-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: hi @Igor  main goal is to add UserId in tables, for all and future queries, in a very efficient, quick way, without manually adding UserId in all the Linq queries, and changing mappers etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF Core [Shadow Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) provide a simple solution to this problem.  Shadow properties exist as columns in the database, but aren't class Properties or Fields on the .NET Entity types.

Comment: so for every Api request with different users,  I can store the userId in a variable, and then parlay to the SQL tables, with shadow properties? slightly edited question above

Comment: Yes.  You simply update the Shadow Properties in an override of DbContext.SaveChanges().